# Android internal storage

Tags: android

I need to store an object in phone internal memory, how can I do this in Android.

Comment: Exactly, what do you want to store?

Answer (score 2):

Hope you find this blog useful.

http://pierrchen.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

Please give more details about what you mean when you say an object? do you mean some a file ?
in case you want to save some files in the internal storage http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Answer (score 0):

To store data refer [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)
In order to store a object in SharedPreferences, you need to make that object class as parcable by implementing [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the serializable on your object and write that object to a file on external storage media. More info visit http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal