# Android : caching object which downloaded from server

Tags: android, caching, proxy, network-protocols

I want to ask how to cache object from server respone like image,  so it can be stored in memory phone or sdcard  , so it can be shared with other activity in next access to the same URL , so it don't need download from the server again.
thanks.

Comment: What are you expecting from people here? The fulll source code of your application? Maybe you should tell us what you've tried so far and what are the main issues you have...

Comment: I'm sorry , I just begin exploring this. I just want to ask how to save or cache object form server respone so it can stored in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You mean how can you store an Object persistently?

That has already been asked several times:

[Android internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590727/android-internal-storage)

[What are the differences among Internal storage, external storage, sd card and removable storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092591/what-are-the-differences-among-internal-storage-external-storage-sd-card-and-re)

[How can I store and retrieve preferences in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030916/store-and-retrieve-preferences-in-android)

If you ask more specific questions we can provide more specific answers

Comment: hope the links help you. Here at stackoverflow when you find an answer useful you should upvote it (press the up arrow next to it). You should also mark the best answer as "accepted" (the "check" arrow next to it)

Comment: @pandre Seem that dkriek just arrived here without taking time to understand the spirit here, got his answer and went elsewhere...